# How can I extract abc.tar.bz2 file?

Tags: command-line, tar

I am planning to install IBM websphere community edition in Ubuntu.

Could you please suggest how can I extract the `wasce_ibm60sdk_setup-3.0.0.4-ppc64linux.tar.bz2` file?

Answer (score 2):

GNU `tar` (comes with Ubuntu) has the needed algorithm built within to detect the compression algorithm used on the archive file.

So you can just do:

```
tar -xf abc.tar.bz2
```

For verbosity, add `-v`:

```
tar -xvf abc.tar.bz2
```

If you want, you can let `tar` know that it is obviously a `bzip2` compressed archive using `-j` (`--bzip2`):

```
tar -xvjf abc.tar.bz2
```

---

If you are into BSD style syntax (without leading `-`) rather than the UNIX one:

```
tar xvjf abc.tar.bz2
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can use:

```
bunzip2 abc.tar.bz2
```

to decompress the archive first, then use `tar` to extract it

```
tar -xfv abc.tar
```